# Как найти центр отрезка на плоскости координат?

Tags: математика, геометрия, координаты

Есть плоскость координат и две известные точки. Как найти центр отрезка?

[image: Плоскость]

Comment: точно искали? это же школьная программа. https://zaochnik.com/spravochnik/matematika/vektory/nahozhdenie-serediny-otrezka/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычный здравый смысл, даже математика не нужна :) Просто **посредине**...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]